# Remove objects from array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

Trying to remove the objects from `NSMutableArray`, below is how addition done to array.

```
sectionInfo = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
```

How tried to remove

```
[sectionInfo removeAllObjects];
```

The error i got is **unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x169cfb70.**
I think it's because i didn't added items in to array ass `addObject:` but that's not my requirement. So, how to manage this.

Comment: Is section info is an NSMutable array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indexPathsForSelectedItems` returns an immutable `NSArray`, regardless of how `sectionInfo` was declared. Theoretically you could do:

```
sectionInfo = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] mutableCopy];
```

Or, if you're just trying to reset `sectionInfo`, you can leave the declaration of `sectionInfo` alone, but then rather than `removeAllObjects`, you could simply say:

```
sectionInfo = nil;
```

Or create a new array:

```
sectionInfo = [NSMutableArray array];
```

I guess it comes down to why you're trying to remove objects from `sectionInfo`, rather than just resetting it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `-[UICollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]` doesn't return a `NSMutableArray`. You want to convert it to a `NSMutableArray` before trying to modify it:

```
sectionInfo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a mutable copy of the `indexPathsForSelectedItems` . Because `indexPathsForSelectedItems` returns `NSArray` not `NSMutableArray`. `NSArray` doesn't have `removeAllObjects` method.

```
sectionInfo = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]mutableCopy];
```